# Using SimpleXML to load remote URL

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to use SimpleXML to load a remote URL.

If I type into my browser the following;

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=12&apiKey=2hkhej72gxyas3ky6hhjtsga&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&customerIpAddress=10.184.2.9&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.25)+Gecko/20111212+Firefox/3.6.25&customerSessionId=&xml=<HotelListRequest><arrivalDate>01/22/2012</arrivalDate><departureDate>01/24/2012</departureDate><RoomGroup><Room><numberOfAdults>1</numberOfAdults><numberOfChildren>1</numberOfChildren><childAges>4</childAges></Room></RoomGroup><city>Amsterdam</city><countryCode>NL</countryCode><supplierCacheTolerance>MED</supplierCacheTolerance></HotelListRequest>
```

It works!

If I try;

```
$url = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=12&apiKey=2hkhej72gxyas3ky6hhjtsga&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&customerIpAddress=10.184.2.9&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.25)+Gecko/20111212+Firefox/3.6.25&customerSessionId=&xml=<HotelListRequest><arrivalDate>01/22/2012</arrivalDate><departureDate>01/24/2012</departureDate><RoomGroup><Room><numberOfAdults>1</numberOfAdults><numberOfChildren>1</numberOfChildren><childAges>4</childAges></Room></RoomGroup><city>Amsterdam</city><countryCode>NL</countryCode><supplierCacheTolerance>MED</supplierCacheTolerance></HotelListRequest> ';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

I get met with the following error;

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=12&apiKey=2hkhej72gxyas3ky6hhjtsga&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&customerIpAddress=10.184.2.9&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0%2B(Windows;%2BU;%2BWindows%2BNT%2B6.1;%2Ben-US;%2Brv:1.9.2.25)%2BGecko/20111212%2BFirefox/3.6.25&customerSessionId=&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%3CarrivalDate%3E01/22/2012%3C/arrivalDate%3E%3CdepartureDate%3E01/24/2012%3C/departureDate%3E%3CRoomGroup%3E%3CRoom%3E%3CnumberOfAdults%3E1%3C/numberOfAdults%3E%3CnumberOfChildren%3E1%3C/numberOfChildren%3E%3CchildAges%3E4%3C/childAges%3E%3C/Room%3E%3C/RoomGroup%3E%3Ccity%3EAmsterdam%3C/city%3E%3CcountryCode%3ENL%3C/countryCode%3E%3CsupplierCacheTolerance%3EMED%3C/supplierCacheTolerance%3E%3C/HotelListRequest%3E%20:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\Program Files\XAMPP\xampplite\htdocs\hotel\results.php on line 29
```

The most notable part of that error is: **parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found**

I would like to access that file and use PHP/SimpleXML to format the results - but thus far I am stuck.

I thought that this thread [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806458/simplexml-load-file-with-ampersand-in-url-with-solr) which talks about rawurlencode may have helped but it didn't, either that or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The results are coming back as json. Replace `simplexml_load_file` with `json_decode` and you will see a proper object.

If you want to use xml, you need to specify it in the headers. The following code will return valid xml:

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=12&apiKey=2hkhej72gxyas3ky6hhjtsga&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&customerIpAddress=10.184.2.9&customerSessionId=&xml=<HotelListRequest><arrivalDate>01/22/2012</arrivalDate><departureDate>01/24/2012</departureDate><RoomGroup><Room><numberOfAdults>1</numberOfAdults><numberOfChildren>1</numberOfChildren><childAges>4</childAges></Room></RoomGroup><city>Amsterdam</city><countryCode>NL</countryCode><supplierCacheTolerance>MED</supplierCacheTolerance></HotelListRequest> ';

$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to return the array but can you tell me what is it about that URL that makes it JSON as it looks like XML to me and also what would be an example of working with the data that gets returned from the above; i.e. echo $xml->hotelId[1]; or something like similar? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The url doesn't specify the encoding - its the Accept header that dose. Your example is pretty much on the right trac, but you should use a separate question for the $XML object part. Please dont forget to accept!