# Consume a C# web service from php in azure

Tags: php, azure

First of all i am going to use REST with JSON because of its simplicity.
So i dont need nusoap etc. The web service is written in C# and runs on azure. After trying i successfully runed a hello word PHP application  on azure. 
My question is how to consume these webservices? The classic php way ? Or use a library from azure for PHP sdk? Because i saw that libraries have a curl and some other functions.

Comment: php provides simplexml_load_file  and json_decode function, which can be passed the uri and returns the responce...Check 1st answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693043/using-simplexml-to-load-remote-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consume Web services written in C# on Azure in the same way as you would consume any Web service running on any platform. Deployment to Azure makes no difference.

The PHP toolkit for Azure (tutorial documentation here: http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/tutorials) is a library for PHP that lets you work with Azure-specific features. This includes

- Azure table, blob and queue storage
- Diagnostics and remote access
- Automating deployment

You won't need anything from the Azure for PHP library to just consume simple a C# Web service.