# PHP Parse a PHP file echoing XML data

Tags: php

I have a php file which generates and echo's XML data.

So basically it shows a XML but it's a PHP file.

I need to read and parse this data.

I've seen this: `simplexml_load_file('some.xml');` but in this case I cannot do this as I've got the xml as a php file.

How can I do this?

Comment: You have to store the XML content is a var if you want to parse it after

Comment: I believe this is an answer you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8693175/1051764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the same way, the file extension doesn't matters (.xml or .php) what it really matters is the actual contents of the file, so if your file have a .php extension but its contents are valid xml then you should have no problem:

```
simplexml_load_file('somepage.php');  //this is fine
```

Comment: I'm getting: Warning: simplexml_load_file() ... Start tag expected, '<' not found in  ...Any ideas why?

Comment: Then your php is not outputting valid xml data, paste the contents on pastebin.com and paste the link here so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Set mime type to xml header('Content-Type:text/xml');