# Parsing xml with php and curl - Expedia API

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

I'm wanting to extract some data from an API call I have made. Using PHP CURL.

Here is my code:

```
    <?PHP
    //use latest minorRev 14
    $url  ='http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=99';
    $url .= '&apiKey=' . $apiKey;
    $url .= '&cid=55505';
    $url .= '&locale=en_US&city=Dallas&stateProvinceCode=TX&countryCode=US&numberOfResults=3';
    $url .= '&searchRadius=50';
    //using the cache returns results much faster
    $url .= '&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED';
    //dates and occupancy
    $url .='&arrivalDate=09/04/2014&departureDate=09/05/2014&room1=2';
    $header[] = "Accept: application/json";
    $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <Tr>
                <TD>

                    <?PHP

                    $hotels = simplexml_load_file('http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=99&apiKey=7z6tduachrht362dpnsch34v&cid=55505&locale=en_US&city=Dallas&stateProvinceCode=TX&countryCode=US&numberOfResults=3&searchRadius=50&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED&arrivalDate=09/04/2014&departureDate=09/05/2014&room1=2');

                    echo $hotels;

                    ?>


                </TD>
            </Tr>
        </table>
```

Why am I not getting anything returned by using the simplexml_load_file function?

I was also following this as a guide - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5

Comment: Maybe you can't just make echo $hotels. Try with `die(var_dump($hotels))` and you'll see what kind of object is $hotels and what does it contain. I don't know fully that function but it seems that you might get an array or an object from it that you'll have to iterate in order to load its content.

Comment: What does the `simplexml_load_file()` call have to do with everything else?

Comment: I've removed your API key from this code. If that was a live key, you probably want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely the guide you've linked, you'll see that the guide tells you to do:

```
echo $mysongs->song[0]->artist;
```

This means that the return of the simplexml_load_file is not a simple string, it's an object, and you'll have to access its data. I'm not sure how to do it but it might look similar to this:

```
foreach($hotels as $hotel){
    echo $hotel;
}
```

You'll have to read better the guide to use it.

As I said in the comment, anytime you're not sure how to access or use an object, running the program with the code `die(var_dump($object));` can help you to get a lot of information of that object and how to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried the foreach loop to no avail. I have also tried accessing my $hotels variable with the var dump but I'm being returned bool(false). Any pointers??

Comment: Hm that means your simplexml_load_file is returning false. Probably it's not being able to read that url. The url works well with the browser so... are you sure that this function is able to read urls? At the guide this function is being used with simple files.

Comment: Take a look at this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693043/using-simplexml-to-load-remote-url

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning the `$response` from your `simplexml_load_file` correctly?

If yes, then remove this line from your code:

```
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
```

And remove the gzip from the `CURLOPT_ENCODING`. Instead use empty which means accept any encodings.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
```

Also, before doing the `json_decode` over the response, just print it or save it into a file and observe that a valid json object is returned from the server or not.

And finally, debug yourself the curl request by enabling the verbose mode.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The API you have is returning data in **JSON** format not **XML**.

```
$hotels = file_get_contents($url);
echo $hotels;
```

this is why `simplexml_load_file` will fail, you have to use `json_decode` instead

---

You parse `JSON` data this way:

```
$data_json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));  
$HotelListResponse = $data_json->{"HotelListResponse"};
$HotelList = $HotelListResponse->{"HotelList"};
$HotelSummary = $HotelList->{"HotelSummary"};
var_dump($HotelSummary);
```

and so forth

---

You can print the hotel name like this:

```
foreach($HotelSummary as $summary){
    $hotelName = $summary->{"name"};
    echo $hotelName."<br />";
}
```