# How do I extract all "TickerSymbol" elements from an external XML file, using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I would like to write a **PHP script to extract all  elements** (and only ticker symbols) from the following external page:
https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all/

So at the time of this writing, the output would be

VAGOV17

DEM.VAGOV17

GOP.VAGOV17

NJGOV17

...

I've tried variations of loadXML() and DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName() but kept getting errors. The XML in the page above appears to be well formed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried and which exact errors did you get while doing so? This isn't a free coding service.

Comment: `$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.@file_get_contents  ('https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all/');  
  
$dom = new DOMDocument;  
$dom -> loadXML($xml);  
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('TickerSymbol');  
foreach ($books as $book) {  
    echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;  
}`  

DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in test_20171008.php on line 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to [load a remote url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693043/using-simplexml-to-load-remote-url).

Then you can use a foreach to loop through all of the data.

Example:

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all/';

$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$elements = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($elements->Markets->MarketData as $marketData) {

    echo $marketData->TickerSymbol . "<br>";

    foreach ($marketData->Contracts->MarketContract as $contract) {
        echo "-" . $contract->TickerSymbol . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Will result in:

```
VAGOV17
-DEM.VAGOV17
-GOP.VAGOV17
NJGOV17
-DEM.NJGOV17
-GOP.NJGOV17
MAYOR.NYC2017
-BDB.MAYOR.NYC2017
-WEINER.MAYOR.NYC2017
-QUINN.MAYOR.NYC2017
-STRINGER.MAYOR.NYC2017
```

Etc..

Answer (score -1):

Here is your Code. Let me know working or not

Hoping your xml file called 'all.xml'

```
<?php 

if (file_exists('all.xml')) 
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('all.xml');

     foreach ($xml as $k)
     {
        $tag =  $k->getName();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($xml->$tag->children() as $key)
        {
            $marketData = $key->getName();

            echo $xml->$tag->MarketData[$i++]->TickerSymbol . "<br>";
        }
     }
}
else
 {
    exit('Failed to open all.xml.');
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work.  Actually I got similar errors in my original code when I used loadXML().     
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): a.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in test_20171009.php on line 4

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): {"Markets":[{"ID":2404,"Name":"Which party will win the 2017 Virginia gubernator in test_20171009.php on line 4

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in test_20171009.php on line 4

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in test_20171009.php on line 6

Comment: What I did is First I save your xml file as all.xml. keep it in same directory. After that run this code. If you still getting error please post a pic of this error . In my case its work fine if you need photo I can give you.

Comment: Thanks Subhendu.  The solution from The Fourth Bird ended up working for me.  Thanks so much for your time and help in any case!